# Syncfusion Chart angular

Tags: angular, syncfusion, ejs-chart

**Syncfusion chart (ejs-chart)**

I am drawing two charts using syncfusion ejs-chart. I want to clear the chart and redraw again with some another data. I am able to remove data from chart but not able to delete it completely .

Comment: Did you try changing the data source? It will redraw the chart.

Comment: Yes. Data source is exactly same as I want. But its not cleared the previous data from the chart.

Comment: I am not sure which chart are you trying, I have created a simple example to change the datasource https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8tk8j-mbjnry?file=app.component.html

Comment: Thanks . I am using ejs-chart for draing chart. My requirement is , In your example When I click the change button i want to remove england from chart and from palette too. So that only one should be there in chart as well as palatte.

Comment: Do you want to implement this feature externally? Clicking on the legend will give the same result. Try clicking on "England" legend placed down to chart.

Comment: I know you are using ejs-chart, that's why I created the example using ejs-chart.I wanted to know the type of chart. like pie, bar, line etc.

Comment: whatever is happening when you click the legend, i want it externally. And i am using multi-line charts

Comment: I have gone through the docs, I didn't see any method to redraw the chart. I tried a kind of hack, here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8tk8j-j7qv9c?file=app.component.html But not sure for best practice.

Answer (score 0):

We suggest you to use chart destroy method, to destroy the chart elements. We have prepared sample based on your requirement. Please check with the below code snippet and sample.

**Code Snippet**

```
export class AppComponent { 
public mode(e: Event): void { 
     this.chart.destroy(); 
} 
public mode1(e: Event): void { 
      this.chart.series[0].dataSource = this.newData; 
      this.chart.refresh(); 
} 
}
```

**Screenshots**

Destroying Chart
[image]
Redrawing Chart
[image]

**Sample** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ydeus-ndxun2?file=app.component.ts